# After post response reload data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Question after I post my data I have a small html table that shows my data however my data doesn't show until I reload the page any help getting this to automatically show my data after I submit will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my angular_stuff

```
var dim = angular.module('Dim', ['ngResource']); 


dim.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) { 
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'; 
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'; 
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'; 
}]); 

dim.config(function ($interpolateProvider) { 
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{'); 
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}'); 
}); 

dim.factory("Dim", function ($resource) { 


    return $resource("_dims.html", { pk: 'pk' }, { 
        index: { method: 'GET', isArray: true, responseType: 'json' }, 
        update: { method: 'POST', responseType: 'json' }, 
        delete: { method: 'DELETE', headers: { 'X_METHODOVERRIDE': 'DELETE' } }, 
    }); 
}) 


dim.service('dataService', function () { 
    this.data = {} 
    this.data.dimMap = new Array(); 
    this.data.dimMap[""] = "description"; 
}); 


//dim.controller("DimController", function($scope, $http, Dim) { 
dim.controller("DimController", function ($scope, $http, Dim) { 
    $scope.dims = Dim.index() 
    //$scope.dims = dataService.data.dimMap; 

    $scope.addDim = function () { 
        dim = Dim.save($scope.newDim) 
        //My guess is I need something here to reload my data ??? 
        $scope.dims.push(Dim) 
        $scope.newDim = {} 


    } 

    $scope.deleteDim = function (index) { 

        dim = $scope.dims[index] 
        Dim.delete(dim) 
        $scope.dims.splice(index, 1); 
    } 
    $scope.newField = {}; 

    $scope.editDim = function (field) { 
        window.console.log($scope.dims[field]); 
        $scope.editing = $scope.dims.indexOf(field); 
        $scope.newField[$scope.editing] = angular.copy(field); 
    } 
})
```

Picture After submit
[image: After Submit]

Data only shows up if I do a manual page realod
[[image: Manual Page Reload[2]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dim.save` is **asynchronous** so when you call `$scope.dims.push(dim)`, `dim` is not yet saved

The solution is to use the success callback of the promise

```
$scope.addDim = function () { 
    Dim.save($scope.newDim).$promise.then(function(dim) {
        $scope.dims.push(dim); 
        $scope.newDim = {}; 
    });
}
```

Comment: @Snowman08 - I think you should query `$scope.dims = Dim.index()` instead of `$scope.dims.push(dim);` inside $promise function, this will get you updated details from DB and will maintain data across all users

Comment: it's not usefull to query again the database, as the post request will return you the created dim from the db you can just do `$scope.dims.push(dim);`

Comment: @oliv37- yes that's right, if there are multiple users using the system then querying will make sure that particular user doesn't get to see only his added data, depends on how he wants to implement

Answer (score 1):

Add **$scope.dims = Dim.index()** at the end of *$scope.addDim* function. It will make a call and you will get the data.